# Exibir quais diretivas estão sendo usadas na página

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Existe alguma forma de descobrirmos quais as diretivas estão sendo usadas em uma página ?

Abaixo segue um exemplo

```
<div>
algumas coisas ...
<minhadiretiva></minhadiretiva>
<minhadiretiva1></minhadiretiva1>
<minhadiretiva2></minhadiretiva2>
outras coisas ...
</div>
```

E aqui está o html da "minhadiretiva"

```
<div>
<minhadiretivafilha></minhadiretivafilha>
<minhadiretivafilha1></minhadiretivafilha1>
<minhadiretivafilha2></minhadiretivafilha2>
</div>
```

Pergunta 1: Como eu posso exibir a lista das diretivas que foram usadas nesta pagina ? (por exemplo no console ou em algum outro lugar)

A resposta para esta pergunta deveria ser

```
minhadiretiva, minhadiretivafilha, minhadiretivafilha1, minhadiretivafilha2, minhadiretiva1, minhadiretiva2
```

Pergunta 2: Se existe uma resposta para a pergunta 1, existe uma maneira de "descobrir" as diretivas usadas usando apenas o console do navegador ? Ou preciso que minhas diretivas sigam algum tipo de padrão ? (ex: algum atributo ou algo desse tipo)

OBS: fiz essa mesma pergunta no stackoverflow gringo, porém não obtive muito interesse por parte da comunidade em responder essa questão. A ideia é trazer essa dúvida para cá e ver se nossa comunidade se interessa mais em respondê-la.

Comment: Se você por `console.log('Nome da diretiva');` ele vai mostrar o nome delas no console.

Answer (score 1):

Existem duas opções (que eu conheço):

- Adicionar console.log manualmente;
- AngularJs Batarang - Extensão para o chrome;

Com o uso do console, é bem simples e direto, basta adicionar um no início de cada diretiva e escrever alguma identificação para ele. Por exemplo:

```
app.directive('minhaDiretiva', function() {
    console.log('minhaDiretiva');
});
```

O problema disso é que é feito manualmente, então pode ser 'trabalhoso'.

---

O outro método é usar o [AngularJs Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk), uma extensão para o chrome que serve como uma ferramenta de análise da sua aplicação. Ele mostra todo o escopo estrutural da sua aplicação, quantidade de watchers, funções, o tempo que cada coisa está tomando de sua aplicação, etc.. É uma ferramenta de análise para que você analise melhor seu projeto.

Não vai ser tão simples de identificar as diretivas se você possuir um projeto muito complexo, com diversas diretivas usadas em conjunto e assim por diante... Mas é uma EXCELENTE ferramenta e, com certeza, você consegue fazer um ótimo debug do projeto.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta ! Sobre as sugestoes, a primeira descartei por ser algo manual e por "sujar" o código fonte, a ideia seria que o programador nao precisasse ficar lembrando disso. Isso também iria sujar demais o console ... Sobre a segunda opção, eu já conhecia o batarang, porém nao consegui utilizá-lo para essa funcionalidade, poderia me dar mais detalhes de como utilizar ? A forma que encontrei até funciona, mas é mt trabalhoso, pois na minha página tenho q ficar focando em cada um dos nodos scope procurando pelo nome da view conforme imagem: https://postimg.org/image/g4vjrcjej/

Comment: @digulino infelizmente os métodos que conheço são esses. Se existe algum outro, ficarei de olho para ficar por dentro também.